# SSAS Invoke-ASCmd create or update not creating db

Tags: azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

I've used the ssas deployment wizard to generate xmla json.  the json starts like this

```
{"sequence": {"operations": [{
  "createOrReplace": {
    "object": {
      "database": "devopstest"
    },
    "database": {
      "name": "devops test",
      "compatibilityLevel": 1400,
      "model": {
        "culture": "en-US",
        "dataSources": [
          ...
```

However when i attempt to deploy this via `Invoke-ASCmd -ConnectionString $constr -InputFile $inputFilePath -Server $server -ServicePrincipal` I get the following error

```
Either the user, '<pii>useraccount</pii>', does not have access to the 'devops test' database, or the database does not exist.
```

The database doesn't exist, as the error points out, but shouldn't it be created?  this xmla json was generated by the deployment wizard both via the UI and CLI.  I first attempted to deploy via CLI and got the same result.  If i run the model through the SSAS deployment wizard UI then the database is created. So why is it that when I run the same model through the CLI of the same exe, or through `Invoke-ASCmd` that it won't create the database.

Comment: Make sure that service principal is an SSAS server level admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my issue.  My connection string in my `deploymenttargets` file had an intitial catalog value set.  If this database didn't exist on the target server, deployments using `Invoke-AScmd` and the SSAS deployment wizard CLI would fail.  However, using the SSAS deployment wizard GUI would succeed.  So I guess what contributed to the confusion was different behaviors of the same application dependent on if it was invoked via CLI or GUI.